# Enhance performance of ABAP report when using OpenSQL query and function call

Tags: abap, sap-erp, opensql

I have an issue with my ABAP report for it being very slow and taking a long time to complete.

My original report had a query to MARA to get all materials into an iTab, loop over it and then query additional tables for each material and store the necessary data and a function call to READ_TEXT in an output iTab.

Since this process takes very long to compete I changed the code to rely more on the database to handle data access instead of making queries for additionoal data each at a time. But still the time to complete is very long for the amount of data to be fetched.

Current code looks like this

```
report z_test_report.

types:
  begin of _output,
    matnr  type mara-matnr,
    text01 type c length 40,
    text02 type c length 40,
    ntgew  type mara-ntgew,
    matkl  type mara-matkl,
    ean11  type mara-ean11,
    preis  type p length 6 decimals 2,
    bstd   type mbew-lbkum,
    laeng  type marm-laeng,
    breit  type marm-breit,
    hoehe  type marm-hoehe,
    volum  type marm-volum,
  end of _output,
  t_output type _output.

data:
  gt_output  type table of t_output,
  gs_output  like line of gt_output,

  gr_table   type ref to cl_salv_table,
  gr_funct   type ref to cl_salv_functions,
  gr_columns type ref to cl_salv_columns_table,
  gr_column  type ref to cl_salv_column.

selection-screen begin of block b01 with frame.
parameters: pa_date type d obligatory.
parameters: pa_kschl type t685-kschl obligatory.
parameters: pa_pltyp type t189-pltyp obligatory.
selection-screen end of block b01.

start-of-selection.
  select
      m~matnr,
      m~ntgew,
      m~matkl,
      m~ean11,
      t~maktx,
      b~lbkum,
      l~laeng,
      l~breit,
      l~hoehe,
      l~volum
  from
      mara as m
    left join
      makt as t
    on
      m~matnr = t~matnr
        and
      t~spras = 'D'
    left join
      mbew as b
    on
      b~matnr = m~matnr
        and
      b~bwkey = '1100'
    left join
      marm as l
    on
      l~matnr = m~matnr
        and
      l~meinh = m~meins
  into
      @data(wa_daten)
  order by
    m~matnr.
    gs_output = corresponding #( wa_daten ).

    select single
      *
    from
      a908
    where
      a908~kappl = 'V'
        and
      a908~kschl = @pa_kschl
        and
      a908~vkorg = '1100'
        and
      a908~pltyp = @pa_pltyp
        and
      a908~matnr = @wa_daten-matnr
        and
      a908~datab < @sy-datum
        and
      a908~datbi > @sy-datum
    into
      @data(gs_a908).
    if ( sy-subrc = 0 ).
      select single
        *
      from
        konp
      where
        konp~knumh = @gs_a908-knumh
      into
         @data(gs_knop).
      if ( sy-subrc = 0 ).
        gs_output-preis = gs_knop-kbetr.
      endif.
    endif.

    data:
      material_name like stxh-tdname,
      textlines     like tline occurs 0,
      textline      like line of textlines.

    material_name = gs_output-matnr.
    call function 'READ_TEXT'
      exporting
        id                      = 'GRUN'
        language                = 'D'
        name                    = material_name
        object                  = 'MATERIAL'
      tables
        lines                   = textlines
      exceptions
        id                      = 1
        language                = 2
        name                    = 3
        not_found               = 4
        object                  = 5
        reference_check         = 6
        wrong_access_to_archive = 7
        others                  = 8.
    if ( sy-subrc = 0 ).
      loop at textlines into textline.
        concatenate gs_output-text02 textline-tdline into gs_output-text02.
      endloop.
    endif.
    condense gs_output-text02.

    append gs_output to gt_output.
  endselect.

  try.
      cl_salv_table=>factory(
        exporting
          list_display = if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false
        importing
          r_salv_table = gr_table
        changing
          t_table = gt_output
      ).
    catch cx_salv_msg.
  endtry.

  gr_funct = gr_table->get_functions( ).
  gr_funct->set_all( abap_true ).
  gr_table->display( ).
```

I think this code can be improved since reading 17k entries from MARA and joining them with the other tables should not be the bottle neck. Changing the old code to the current one reduced the runtime from about 45s down to 30s, removing the READ_TEXT only made the report take about 5s less.

If anyone has an idea it would be really appreciated. Or if anyone knows a tool to measure report performance to find out about bottle necks.

Comment: There are still SELECT SINGLEs inside the SELECT...ENDSELECT. These should be replaced with a FOR ALL ENTRIES solution (if JOIN is not possible). The READ_TEXT FM can be replaced with READ_MULTIPLE_TEXTS, so you can select all texts in one go.

Comment: Ty for your response! I tried fetching data from A908+KNOP within the main query but I found no solution. Will try the mentioned FM for reading multiple texts

Comment: For code review, you could post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to Code Review